# Using General Unicode Properties

Tags: regex, unicode

I am trying to take advantage of the regex functionality : \p{UNICODE PROPERTY NAME}

However, I am struggling with understanding the a mapping of those property names.

I went direct to the Unicode.org website ( http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/) and downloaded a file 'UnicodeData.txt' which has the catagory listed... but this only shows 27,268 character values.

But I understand there are 65k characters in utf-8 or ucs-2 .... so I am confused why the Unicode.org download only has 24k rows.

... am I missing a point here somewhere ?

I am sure I'm just being blind to something simple here ... if someone can help me understand.... I'd be grateful !

Comment: Well, it seems several *thousands* of Chinese (Hangul) glyphs are omitted: `AC00;<Hangul Syllable, First>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;; ... 
D7A3;<Hangul Syllable, Last>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine so far. The characters you see are *all* but the CJK ones (Chinese-Japanese-Korean). The Unicode consortium let those out of the main UnicodeData file to keep it at a reasonable size.

If you want to look up properties for single characters only (and not for bulks), you can use websites, that prepare that data for you, like [Graphemica](http://graphemica.com), [FileFormat](http://fileformat.info) or (my own) [Codepoints.net](http://codepoints.net).

If, however, you need bulk lookups, Unicode also provides the data as an [XML file](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr42/) with a specific syntax, that groups codepoints together. That might be the best choice for processing the data.

Comment: Super fantastic!  I did post this Q on another forum on Friday with no useful responses. Yet again StackOverflow hits the mark with fast and informative responses..... why didn't I come here first !?   Boldewyn, thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome. And I hope this was a lesson to you not to cheat on StackOverflow with other forums ;-)